# QStringList multiple entries and comparison

Tags: qt5

I am using `QInputDialog::getText` to allow the user to input a string. The user should enter an arbitrary number of comma separated integers.

Then I would like to check if there is a duplicate.

In order to convert the input to integers, I have tried the following:

1. Split the input into a list using the `QString::split` with comma as an argument
2. Iterate over the elements of the `QStringList`

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= list.count(); i++)
   {
       list.at(i).toInt();
   }
   ```

The loop leads to a crash.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause

Because the element index in the list is zero-based, i.e. starts from `0` and runs up to `count - 1`, your loop tries to access a non-existing element with index `count` and your program crashes.

## Solution

Either change

```
for (int i = 1; i <= list.count(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
```

or even better, use a *ranged for*

```
for (const QString &substr : list)
```

Then use [`QList::takeFirst()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#takeFirst) and [`QList::contains`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#contains) in a `while` loop to check for duplicates.

## Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString &str(QInputDialog::getText(nullptr, "Input integers",
                                             "Enter comma separated integers."
                                             " Do not use spaces."));
    QList<int> numbers;
    bool hasDuplicate = false;

    for (const QString &substr : str.split(','))
        numbers.append(substr.toInt());

    while (numbers.count() && !hasDuplicate)
        hasDuplicate = numbers.contains(numbers.takeFirst);

    QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Result",
                             hasDuplicate ? "There is at least one duplicate"
                                          : "All numbers are unique");

    return 0;
}
```

## Result

- For the example input of

  ```
  11,22,33
  ```

this message is shown

[image: Message window: All numbers are unique]

- For the example input of

  ```
  11,22,33,22
  ```

this message is shown

[image: Message window: There is at least one duplicate]